# Show keyboard layout chart from command line

Tags: command-line, gnome, keyboard-layout

I'm looking for a way to display the current keyboard layout chart from the command line.

Unfortunately `xkbprint` does not display utf-8 characters correctly (AFAICT).

In gnome, it is possible to click on the keyboard layout indicator applet and then "Show Layout Chart", which does the same thing as going through the menus of `gnome-control-center` (btw, `gnome-control-center keyboard` is not an acceptable solution), so there must be a way to trigger an event that would pop up this window, right?

Note that most of the time I don't use `gnome-panel`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l keyboard_layout[(variant)]
```

For example, to show Greek keyboard layout chart from command line:

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l gr
```

To show US AltGr International keyboard variant:

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l "us(altgr-intl)"
```

For a complete list of layouts, see https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/en/man7/xkeyboard-config.7.html#layouts

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot! I've been looking for this for several hours!

Comment: +1 I had to install `gkbd-keyboard-display` from package `gkbd-capplet`..

Comment: nice and simple :)

Comment: The command `gkbd-keyboard-display -l us,altgr-intl` causes a segmentation fault for me.  `gkbd-keyboard-display -l "us(altgr-intl)"` works, though.

Comment: Is there a way to show the currently selected input method instead?

Comment: I think I found out how: `gkbd-keyboard-display -g 1`

Comment: @ToDo - what that does is to show the first/default kb image. `2` shows the second, `3` the third and so forth. Useful, but it doesn't *show* the already selected kb, it *selects* the kb in numerical order.

Comment: @ToDo - looking up the help there isn't a way to show the already selected layout, we have to specify the layout or the number: `-g, --group=group number (1, 2, 3, 4)           Group to display`

Answer (score 1):

(Mis-)interpreting the requirement "from the command line" as "without touching the mouse", a convenient way in a casual Gnome environment is to create a desktop file that starts the "gkdb-keyboard-tool" from the activities overview.

As setup, create the following file:

```
~/.local/share/applications/show-keyboard-layout.desktop
```

With the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Show keyboard layout
Comment=
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Yaru/256x256/devices/input-keyboard.png
Exec=gkbd-keyboard-display -l "us(altgr-intl)"
Terminal=false
Categories=Utility
```

Press ALT-F2, and enter 'r' to restart the Gnome desktop if you use X11, otherwise restart your session.

To open the layout window, press the Super key (e.g. Windows key), and then enter the first letters of "Show keyboard layout" until the proper entry is shown. Finally, press enter.

The layout shown is hard coded. You can query the keyboard currently used with the following command and adapt the .desktop file accordingly.

```
setxkbmap -query
```

Comment: To change layout, variant, option etc, you need to know what you can select with what.  Try `localectl list-x11-keymaps-models`, `localectl list-x11-keymaps-layouts`, `localectl list-x11-keymaps-variants us` etc. Then use `setxkbmap`  to test until it work as you want.  Then you can use `localectl set-x11-keymap ...` to set it "permanently" so it work at next login.  Use `man` pages to see more options.

Answer (score 0):

**Current** keyboard layout chart onliner (using `awk` and `localectl`):

```
gkbd-keyboard-display -l $(localectl status | awk '/X11 Layout/ {print $3}')$'\t'$(localectl status | awk '/X11 Variant/ {print $3}')
```

On an alias, [using string literal syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55528377/4970442):

```sh
alias current_keyboard_layout_chart=$'gkbd-keyboard-display -l $(localectl status | awk \'/X11 Layout/ {print $3}\')$\'\t\'$(localectl status | awk \'/X11 Variant/ {print $3}\')'
```

Also, you can [generate a PDF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/520842/209677) or use [xkeycaps](https://www.jwz.org/xkeycaps/).