# Shift keys not working properly

Tags: keyboard

I have recently returned to using my netbook and have discovered that the shift keys work for certain characters but not for others. Typing most lower-case letters is okay, but I cannot type uppercase q, w, r, y, u, etc. This also applies to the curly right curly brace, the pipe character, etc. Is this a hardware or software problem? The netbook is from ASUS, though I forget the exact model, and there may have been water damage. Solutions?
EDIT: I have recently found out that I can type the symbol or capital letter by letting go of the shift key first before letting go of the symbol/letter key. For example, to type a capital R, I have to hold down the shift key, then hold down the R key, then release the shift key.

Comment: Seems a hardware issue. Testing your keyword with [`libinput debug-events`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/libinput.1.html) or [`evtest`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/evtest.1.html) return any activity? Did you try an external USB keyboard? Does your [current layout](https://askubuntu.com/a/1381068/349837) match your real physical keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your machine has a dual boot, but I had the same issue. Both my <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys suddenly stopped working for no apparent reason  while I was using Linux.

The way I fixed it was booting in Windows and deactivating the *Sticky Keys* shortcut (that gets activated by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> 5 times, or holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> for some seconds). Maybe you should give that a try.