# Login Screen Changed and Login not working

Tags: 16.04, login, display, login-screen

Actually, in the initial case, my ctrl and shift button were not working properly, so I followed the answers posted in this link:
[Shift keys not working properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/641067/shift-keys-not-working-properly),
I run the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
sudo apt-get install console-common
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

But when I restarted, a different kind of login screen is getting displayed, and when I tried logging in with password, I am getting this message: "**unable to get the valid context for (user)**" and jumping back to same screen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu 16.04 login to a virtual console by pressing the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> To login from a virtual console:

1. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After logging in run the following commands:

```
sudo apt update   
sudo apt upgrade   
sudo apt purge lightdm  
sudo apt install lightdm  
sudo reboot
```

Reconfigure the LightDM login display manager:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm 
sudo reboot
```

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` will open up a new window allowing you to select lightdm as the default login display manager. Use the arrow keys to select lightdm, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to put the focus on **<OK>** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then reboot by running `sudo reboot`

Comment: as I am not able to login, I loggedin through recover mode and tried the command you mentioned, it says "lightdm is broken or not fully installed". I tried installing it using "apt-get install lightdm", but getting  error says "unable to fetch archives", then I tried updating it with "apt-get update --fix-missing", but still not working

Comment: it worked now, from the current login screen, i moved to console login screen using ctrl_alt-f1. In recovery mode, the network connection was not working properly. Thanks karel.